# Prime numbers in large number

Tags: code-golf, number, primes

Given a large number (in base 10), such as 1234567891011121314151617, find prime "subnumbers" in it.
A prime "subnumber" is a consecutive sequence of digits (taken from the input), which represents a prime number (in base 10).

- **Input**:
  A number (either a string, a file, or whatever you like).
- **Output**:
  All prime subnumbers separated somehow (either in a list, a file, comma-separated strings...)
  If the result is empty, you can take any convention you like (hardcoded string, empty string, gibberish, but program should not crash.
- **Example**
  1234 -> 2, 3, 23
  6542 -> 5, 2
  14 -> [.. empty output]

This is code-golf. The shortest program wins!
[edit] : additional rule, program must be explained! Not everybody is fluent in Jelly :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [Extremely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18592/find-the-largest-contiguous-prime-in-a-string).

Comment: Must duplicates be included, excluded, or may we do either?

Comment: not specified. Do whatever you like.

Comment: For future reference using an @ you can notify one user (like @JonathanAllan)

Comment: Tip: That's too soon to be accepting an answer; it can discourage others from posting solutions.

Comment: @RegisPortalez welcome, and nice challenge! I've found that the "accept" feature isn't used all that much anymore on PPCG the way it is on the other sites in the network. We tend to value nice answers in any language.

Comment: @Shaggy you're right. 05AB1E solution will probably be accepted later on though :)

Comment: Can we take a vector of digits as input ? e.g. [1,2,3,4] for 1234 ?

Comment: @digEmAll : « or whatever you like » . Yes you can

Comment: @RegisPortalez: needed to be sure, thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 3 bytes

```
Œʒp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6KRTkwr@/zc2MTUzBwA)

Substrings of the input that are prime.

Comment: That will be hard to make shorter :)

Comment: Right language for this task

Comment: This is 3 characters, but not 3 bytes, no?

Comment: @mob That depends on the encoding. In the [05AB1E encoding](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), this answer is 3 bytes long.

Comment: According to this, 34567 = 13*2659 is prime, seems wrong : https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6KRTkwr@/zc2MTUzBwA

Comment: @frosqh It's actually a bug of the p (prime) function in the new 05AB1E release: https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6KRTkwr@/zc2MTUzBwA 
It's already been fixed in the repository but hasn't been pushed on TIO. I've switched my answer to the legacy version in the meantime.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](http://www.perl6.org/), 28 bytes

```
{grep &is-prime,+«m:ex/.+/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Or0otUBBLbNYt6AoMzdVR/vQ6lyr1Ap9PW392v/FiZUKSirxCrZ2CtVpCirxtUoKaflFCjaGRsYmCmamJkYKhiZ2/wE)

The `:ex` ("exhaustive") flag to the match operator `m` makes it return every possible match of `.+` (ie, every substring of one or more characters), even overlapping ones.  The hyperoperator `+«` turns that list of `Match` objects into numbers, which are then filtered for primeness by `grep &is-prime`.

Comment: Here I was going to go with `{+«m:ex/(.+)<?{$0.is-prime}>/}`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills I tried that too!  I'm a little disappointed it turned out to be longer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining - always helpful to Perl 4 dinosaurs like me!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```python
P=k=1
n=input()
while~n+k:
 if`k`in`n`>0<P%k:print k
 P*=k*k;k+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8A229aQK882M6@gtERDk6s8IzMntS5PO9uKSyEzLSE7ITMvIS/BzsAmQDXbqqAoM69EIZtLIUDLNlsr2zpb29bw/39DQwA)

Comment: Should be `while k<=n` or, to cost 0 bytes, `while~n+k`

Comment: @JonathanAllan thank you. At first I thought the number itself should be excluded from the output, but it seems like this isn't the case.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Can you explain please the code from the `while` statement? I haven't seen this type of codes before. Also haven't seen use of **``** , what it does?

Comment: @taritgoswami `while stmt:` will run as long as `stmt` has a value that is considered truthy by python. The only falsy integer in Python is `0`. Therefore the code will run as `~n+k != 0`. `~` is the bitwise complement operator, and `~n` is equivalent to `-n - 1`. `~n + k != 0` <=> `-n - 1 + k != 0` <=> `k != n + 1`. As we are incrementing `k` by `1` in every operation, `k != n + 1` is in this case equivalent to `k <= n`.

Comment: @taritgoswami And `\`n\`` is the same as `repr(n)` in Python 2. (does not work in Python 3).

Comment: @ovs: I have trouble to grasp the mathematical principle behind the use of `P*=k*k` / `P%k>0`... is it perhaps a corollary to the Euclid's Lemma ?

Comment: @digEmAll This is based on [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem). `P` keeps track of `(k-1)! ^ 2`, while k iterates through all integers between `1` and `n`. A explanation of this method can be found in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/64121).

Comment: @ovs: thanks, very useful !

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Kroppeb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81957/kroppeb).

```
sᶠṗˢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/jhtgUPd04/vej/f0MjY5P/UQA)

`ᶠ`ind all `s`ubstrings, `ˢ`elect the `ṗ`rimes

Comment: `sᶠṗˢ` is one byte shorter. It finds all substrings and returns those which are prime.
See here https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117871/81957

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

*Thanks @Shaggy -3 bytes*

```
ò fj f@søX
```

---

```
ò fj f@søX              Full program
                        implicity input
ò                       inclusive range [this - 1]
  fj                    filter primes and
     f@søX              values contained in input
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8iBmaiBmQHP4WA==&input=MTIzNCAtUQ==)

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AmhbQshTSH4sM7Iv7/NzQyNlHQDQQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>5</s>  4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

-1 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen (`Ẓ` is an alias for `ÆP`)

```
ẆḌẒƇ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of digits* which yields a list of prime integers.

<sup>* going by "either a string, a file, or whatever you like" - to take an integer, prefix the code with a `D`</sup>

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrraHO3oe7pp0rP3////RhjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWOpY6hjoGQAyCRkBsDMQmQGwKxGZAbB4LAA)**

#### How?

```
ẆḌẒƇ - Link: list of integers (digits)   e.g. [1,2,3,4]
Ẇ    - non-empty contiguous substrings        [[1],[2],[3],[4],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
 Ḍ   - convert to decimal (vectorises)        [1,2,3,4,12,23,34,123,234,1234]
   Ƈ - filter keep if:
  Ẓ  -   is prime?                            [2,3,23]
```

Comment: `ÆP` can be `Ẓ` if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Ah yes that is one of the new aliases - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>148</s> 147 bytes

```java
n->{for(int l=n.length(),i=l,j;i-->0;)for(j=l;j>i;){long k=2,x=new Long(n.substring(i,j--));for(;k<x;x=x%k++<1?0:x);if(x>1)System.out.println(x);}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVDLboMwELznK1ZIlWwFo5g8KsUxPVdq00OOVQ8OIanBMQiblCri26kh5NBHVB8s7ezM7sym4iRIusvaWAlj4FlIfR4BSG2Tci/iBNZdCXDK5Q5itLGl1AcwmDm0GbnPWGFlDGvQwKHVJDrv8xI5PSiuA5Xog31H2Jdc@SmThEQThjtGyhVLI8nwWeVuYsZDv@Y6@YAnVyIdmGpr@mVI@ikhGLNOxbJVzWpe32Xj8Yo@TJY1ZnKP6ojizaexyTHIKxsUTmeVRq7ZNC3rbBbVVjmbg9s@zdFlHQK9voHAl6A2MRZ5NJzOvD7kFVnMZ@F3hP5g0JBO6YzO6YLee78O1K/sicMNpS4qOyz9w7v32PWX4I0vRHaT@FLZjnk1o4MY/Scht97Vd9N@AQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                     // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(int l=n.length(),  //  Length of the input-String
          i=l,j;         //  Temp-integers
      i-->0;)            //  Loop `i` in the range [length, 0)
    for(j=l;j>i;){       //   Inner loop `j` in the range [length, 0)
      for(long k=2,      //    Set `k` to 2
               x=new Long(n.substring(i,j--)
                         //    Take the substring [`i`, `j`) from the input,
            );           //    convert it to a long, and set it as `x`
          k<x;           //    Inner loop as long as `k` is still smaller than `x`
        x=x%k++<1?       //     If `x` is divisible by `k`:
           0             //      Set `x` to 0
          :              //     Else:
           x);           //      Leave `x` unchanged
      if(x>1)            //    If `x` is now larger than 1 (a.k.a. If `x` is a prime):
        System.out.println(x);}}
                         //     Print `x` with a trailing newline to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
&XfXUtZp)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xy0iLSK0JKpA8/9/dUMjYxN1AA)

#### Explanation

```
&Xf   % Implicit input: string. Push cell array of non-empty substrings
XU    % Convert to number. Vectorizes
t     % Duplicate
Zp    % Isprime. Vectorizes.
)     % Index. Keeps substrings indicated by the previous result. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + GNU Core Utils: <s>80</s> 77 Bytes

```
for i in $(seq `tee a|wc -c`)
{
grep -oE .{$i}<a|factor|grep -oP ': \K\d+$'
}
```

This cannot be the shortest, but I am having trouble coming up with anything better. Help wanted!

By sticking to only POSIX, I got 82:

```
for i in $(seq `tee a|wc -c`)
{
grep -oE .{$i}<a|factor|awk -F\  'NF<3{print$2}'
}
```

Comment: Could Bash string slicing help?  It's a shame brace ranges are expanded before parameters...

Comment: @TobySpeight that would require two loops (one for the start, one for the end), not to mention you can't use variables inside of a slicing substitution. Zsh allows it, though! The main route to shortness in my mind is to use Awk to generate all the substrings.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 60 bytes

```r
function(v)Filter(function(i)grepl(i,v)&sum(!i%%1:i)==2,1:v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcgxCoAwDEDRvbdwUBJwSVsVhK5eRBoJaJWqvX5EB6fP@1k5KN9pvmRPUHCS9YoZ/iO45HisIG3B5rw3qKSuaRQMwbY0FlQGss6jYeg7b9/SJ@/o0@C7waGqeQA)

Not really efficient, inspired by @ovs python 2 answer

Comment: Awesome! [funprog](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) rules!

Answer (score 2):

## [Curry (KiCS2)](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/), <s>61</s> 58 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)!

Takes input as a string, returns integers. `f` is function which can return any of the results.

```haskell
p n|n>1&&all((>0).mod n)[2..n-1]=n
f(_++a:b++_)=p$read$a:b
```

You can try this on [Smap](https://smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap.cgi?new/curry) (select `KiCS2 2.2.0 /all-values`) by adding:

```haskell
main = f "1234"
```

`p` is a primality test function which returns it's input if it is a prime, and doesn't return anything otherwise.

`f(_++a:b++_)` matches non-empty substrings of the input in `a:b` and `f` returns the value of `p` applied to `a:b` converted to integer.

Local output:

```haskell
> f "1234"
[...]
Evaluating expression: f "1234"
2
23
3
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṡ`, 4 bytes

```
ǎE~æ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaAiLCIiLCLHjkV+w6YiLCIiLCIxMjM0Il0=)

```
ǎE~æ # 'Ṡ' flag makes Vyxal take all input as strings
ǎ    # All substrings
 E   # Convert to numbers
  ~æ # Remove non-primes
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>115</s> 114 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and[n for n in[int(s[j:])for j in range(len(s))]if n>1and all(n%i for i in range(2,n))]+f(s[:-1])or[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxDgIhFAV7T/EbAz9qAa4WJHoRQoHZRdngYwPbeHpECy3fZOYtr/WRoVsLl@Sft9FTNZU8RgsKuRAowkasstrZOP6guSMqHvdJpgmyMrsYCFfVK/IpSWzjt41/Ue/RtV3oN@agHOdiXVtKP6YghdLHQfDmt8@nQQtubw)

Comment: `if~-n*all(n%i for i in range(2,n))` saves 4.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
Select[PrimeQ@*FromDigits]@*Subsequences
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/A/ODUnNbkkOqAoMzc10EHLrSg/1yUzPbOkONZBK7g0qTi1sDQ1Lzm1@D9QRV5JdFp0taGOgpGOgrGOgkltbCwXXNhMR8EUKAaURBE2hKj7DwA)

Input and output are lists of digits. In the case of no prime subnumbers the empty list `{}` is returned.

Uses `@*` for [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) of functions. [`Subsequences`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsequences.html) gives a list of all subsequences of the input, and `Select[PrimeQ@*FromDigits]` is an operator form of [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) which returns a list of all elements for which `PrimeQ@*FromDigits` returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
foṗiQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py3/4c7pmYH///9XMjQyNlECAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 108 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List
$s=nub[n\\u<-inits s,n<-map(toInt o toString)(tails u)|n>1&&all(\m=n/m*m<n)[2..n-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc3NCoJAEADge0@xhyiNtMb@QTvVIegQeFQPk1os7MyGOwZBz94WdPxOX21aZE@26U2rCDV7TQ/bicqlOfJzekDB@KydDIYu4/5acFn2aaRZi1NuymlE@AjEnliUVWJz6TTfw0BQG6f68M17GI3QmKCkjGc0oZTDIoljjqCqfC74uzI1VMUYksVytd5sdzAHgAQWsIQVrGEzrvynvhm8Ox@dzv7wYiRd/3ExKDfb0Rc)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
fP_TsM.:
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fP_TsM.%3A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%221234%22%0A%226542%22%0A%2214%22&debug=0)

Takes the input as a string, outputs a list of integers. Can also take input as an `int` [by adding `` ` `` at the end](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fP_TsM.%3A%60&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1234%0A6542%0A14&debug=0) for an extra byte.

Explanation:

```
fP_TsM.:  | Full code
fP_TsM.:Q |  with implicit variables added
          | Print (implicit)
      .:Q |  list of all substrings of the input
    sM    |   converted to integers
fP_T      |    filtered for prime numbers
```

And `` ` `` just converts `int` to `str`.

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab, 89 bytes

```
function[m]=f(x),m=1;for i=1:length(x),m=[m;str2num(combnk(x,i))];end,m=m(isprime(m));end
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##JclBDoMgEADAr3hzN/GCsT1IeAnxUCnUjd3FIDT8Htv0OhNdfnx8a6GIyxTF8mICVBzYKB1i6sio@e3llbe/WtZnTqMUBhd5lR3qQIiL9vL8NgOdRyL2wIg/awH6@20ae2wX)